# I get a Black Screen when i am running my code

Tags: python, screen

Heyy, im really new to this and stumbled into a problem but i can't seem to find the reason for this.

```
import pygame
import random

# Initialisierung von Pygame
pygame.init()

# Konstanten
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
QIX_SPEED = 3
RED = (255, 0, 0)
num_positions = 5
min_x = 50
min_y = 50
qix_path = []
qix_path = []


# Spielbildschirm einrichten
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Qix Clone")

# Spieler-Charakter
class Player:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 20
        self.height = 20
        self.speed = 1
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 20, 20)

        # Setze die Anfangsposition am linken Rand
        self.x = 0
        self.y = HEIGHT // 2

    # Datenstruktur Qix-Felder
    class QixField:
        def __init__(self, cell_size, width, height):
            self.cell_size = cell_size
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.rows = height // cell_size
            self.cols = width // cell_size
            self.grid = [[False for _ in range(self.cols)] for _ in range(self.rows)]
            self.total_cells = self.rows * self.cols

    qix_field = QixField(20, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    def move(self, qix_field):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            new_x = self.x - self.speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            new_x = self.x + self.speed
        else:
            new_x = self.x
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            new_y = self.y - self.speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            new_y = self.y + self.speed
        else:
            new_y = self.y

        # Überprüfen, ob neue Position im Qix-Feld nicht erobert ist
        x = new_x // qix_field.cell_size
        y = new_y // qix_field.cell_size
        if not qix_field.grid[y][x]:
            self.x = new_x
            self.y = new_y

    def conquer_qix(self, qix_field):
        x = self.x // qix_field.cell_size
        y = self.y // qix_field.cell_size
        if not qix_field.grid[y][x]:
            qix_field.grid[y][x] = True


# Qix
class Qix:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 64
        self.height = 64
        self.speed = 2


def generate_qix_path(num_positions, min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y):
    qix_path = []
    for _ in range(num_positions):
        x = random.randint(min_x, max_x)
        y = random.randint(min_y, max_y)
        qix_path.append((x, y))
    return qix_path

def check_victory(qix_field):
    conquered_cells = sum(row.count(True) for row in qix_field.grid)
    return conquered_cells >= 0.76 * qix_field.total_cells

# Spiel-Schleife
running = True
player = Player(WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2)
qix = Qix(random.randint(50, WIDTH - 50), random.randint(50, HEIGHT - 50))

# Setze die Anfangsposition des Spielers am Rand des Spielfelds
player = Player(20, HEIGHT // 2)  # Anfangsposition am linken Rand

qix_field = Player.QixField(20, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

while running:
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


            old_qix_path = qix_path
            qix_path = []

            # Qix-Pfad generieren
            qix_path = generate_qix_path(5, 100, WIDTH - 50, 100, HEIGHT - 50)
            qix_index = 0  # Der Index, der die aktuelle Position im Pfad angibt



            if qix_index < len(old_qix_path):
                target_x, target_y = old_qix_path[qix_index]
                if qix.x < target_x:
                    qix.x += qix.speed
                elif qix.x > target_x:
                    qix.x -= qix.speed
                if qix.y < target_y:
                    qix.y += qix.speed
                elif qix.y > target_y:
                    qix.y -= qix.speed

                if qix.x == target_x and qix.y == target_y:
                    qix_index += 1

    # Spielerbewegung
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.x -= player.speed
        print(keys)
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.x += player.speed
        print(keys)
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.y -= player.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.y += player.speed

#Spielfigur und Spielersteuerung gleichstellen
    player.rect.x = player.x
    player.rect.y = player.y

for y, row in enumerate(qix_field.grid):
    for x, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (x * qix_field.cell_size, y * qix_field.cell_size, qix_field.cell_size, qix_field.cell_size))


 # Qix-Bewegung
qix.x += random.uniform(-qix.speed, qix.speed)
qix.y += random.uniform(-qix.speed, qix.speed)

# Begrenze die Positionen des Spielers und des Qix auf den Bildschirm
player.x = max(0, min(player.x, WIDTH - player.width))
player.y = max(0, min(player.y, HEIGHT - player.height))
qix.x = max(0, min(qix.x, WIDTH - qix.width))
qix.y = max(0, min(qix.y, HEIGHT - qix.height))

# Kollisionserkennung zwischen Spieler und Qix
player_rect = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)
qix_rect = pygame.Rect(qix.x, qix.y, qix.width, qix.height)

if player_rect.colliderect(qix_rect):
    qix.x = random.randint(50, WIDTH - 50)
    qix.y = random.randint(50, HEIGHT - 50)

    player.move(player.qix_field)
    player.conquer_qix(player.qix_field)

    if check_victory(qix_field):
        print('is this how you get your sick Qix???')

    # Zeichne Spieler und Qix
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, player.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, qix_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

# Pygame beenden
pygame.quit()
```

i tried excluding a few blocks of code i thought could be the cause of the problem like the Qix Field Class but i didnt find anything. perhaps i missed something?
I even tried finding a solution through chatGPT but it didnt help very much.
i don't get any error messages either and I have no idea of debugging as of now.

Comment: what is the actual problem ?  this code will not run because there is no instance of the class and it doesn't do anything.  looks like most of the code is missing... the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)